# How to reshape a data frame with duplicate column names as rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a data set (that has been imported from a .json file) that currently looks like this:

```
ID <- c(1)
Name <- c("John")
Name.1 <- c("Irene")
Address <- c("1 Brick Lane")
Address.1 <- c("2 Wood Street")

df <- data.frame(ID, Name, Name.1, Address, Address.1)

ID     |  Name |   Address    | Name.1 | Address.1
------ | ------|   ------     | ------ | ------
1      | John  | 1 Brick Lane | Irene  | 2 Wood Street
```

However, I would like to manipulate it to look like this:

```
ID <- c(1)
Name <- c("John", "Irene")
Address <- c("1 Brick Lane", "2 Wood Street")

df <- data.frame(ID, Name, Address)

ID     |  Name |   Address    
------ | ------|   ------     
1      | John  | 1 Brick Lane 
1      | Irene | 2 Wood Street
```

Also, not all people have the same information fields. For example, John's date of birth might be in the data but Irene's is not.

In my real data set there would be about 30 different columns in the final data frame. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `melt` from `data.table` which can take multiple `measure` patterns

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^Name", "^Address"),
      value.name = c("Name", "Address"))[, variable := NULL][]
#   ID  Name       Address
#1:  1  John  1 Brick Lane
#2:  1 Irene 2 Wood Street
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for my smaller example, but for my data set with more than 50 variables, I am now getting an error saying 
 "Error in melt.data.table(setDT(df), id = ID,  : Unsupported type 'NULL' ".

Does anyone have any knowledge as to why? I have run it line by line and cannot seem to find the issue. 

Also, is there a way to not write out every single variable by name? Especially as each of my data sets may have different variable names.

Comment: @nspoljar Not clear about the error.  Could you please update your post with a small example that shows the error

Comment: I have fixed the error and figured out the second part of my question. Thank you very much though!